# Creating static table header with ScrollView

Tags: android, static, header, scrollview, tableview

I have a table inside a ScrollView will one column that contain several buttons. My goal is to add a header to the top of the column, so as you scroll down the header stays with you.

I have done some researching on this subject and have tried things such as the "dummy" row, but not sure how to get that working.

Here is what I have so far trying, but the header doesn't move with you as you scroll.
Thanks in advance.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation='horizontal' >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >


    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/table_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left" >

       <TableLayout 
           android:id="@+id/header"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TableRow>
        <TextView android:id="@+id/header_tab1"
           android:textColor="@android:color/black"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal"
           android:text="Header_tb1" > 
           </TextView>
        </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

      <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Header_tb1" >     
         </TextView>
         </TableRow>


        <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_1_tb1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Button1"
                android:textSize="23sp" >   
             </Button>
           </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_2_tb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Button2"
                    android:textSize="23sp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

         <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_3_tb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Button3"
                    android:textSize="23sp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow> 

         <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_4_tb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button4"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Button4"
                    android:textSize="23sp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

          <TableRow android:id="@+id/row_5_tb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button5"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Button5"
                    android:textSize="23sp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

          <TableRow android:id="@+id/row6_tb1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <Button android:id="@+id/Button6"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/Button6"
                    android:textSize="23sp" > 
                </Button>
            </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>  
         </ScrollView>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood your question, you can create one more table layout upper outside scroll view and this table layout will be your table header..